# When using bitbake/yocto, is there a way to conditionally append a task?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I know how to conditionally append variables, but is there a way in which to append/prepend things to tasks in a recipe depending on the value of some variables?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is using `OVERRIDES` variable.

```
OVERRIDES = 'somecond'

VAR_X = '123'
VAR_X_append_somecond = '456'
VAR_X_append_othercond = '789'
```

In this case, `VAR_X` will be `123456` because `somecond` is in the `OVERRIDES` variable. Refer here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#conditional-syntax-overrides

Comment: Note that these days the underbar is replaced with a colon: `VAR_X:append:somecond = '456'`. This example actually nicely demonstrates why.